# Can we find $t\in \mathbb R$ such that the roots of $tx^2-2x+2t=0$ are rational?

Tags: inequality, roots, quadratics, rational-numbers

Can we find $t\in \mathbb R$ such that the roots of $tx^2-2x+2t=0$ are rational ?

**MY ATTEMPT**

For $t\neq 0$
$$tx^2-2x+2t=0$$

$$x=\frac{1\pm\sqrt{1-2t^2}}{t}$$
.
Suppose that $x\in \mathbb Q $, thus $x \in \mathbb R$ .

Therefore $$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \leq t \leq\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$$

Thus $1-2t^2$ is always less than $1$. Never equal to 1. (Since $t \neq 0$)

So I am left with the only option (from my perspective) that is $1-2t^2 = \frac{1}{c^2}$ where $c>1$

I am stuck here. I feel Like there is no such $t \in \mathbb R$

Comment: Yes, we can!  Take $t=\sqrt3/3$ for example.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe The question asks for both roots to be rational,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $x=1$ and get a value of $t$.

Or take $t=\frac{2x}{x^2+2},$ where $x$ is a rational number.

Comment: You're right; I'll delete my previous comment.

Comment: So the answer is " There exist $t$ such that $t \in (-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}},0)\cup(0,\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})$. Not for all $t$ in that range.

Comment: @Angelo Mark Yes, but you can take any $t=\frac{2a}{a^2+2},$ where $a$ is a non-zero rational number.